# android.support.v7.app.ActivityCompat not found

Tags: android

Having an issue with the import android.support.v7.app.ActivityCompat not being recognized.

In looking at the following location:

/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7

I see that there are many directories, but every directory is empty. ??  Shouldn't there be files in there?  If so, is there a way to just update Android and not android-studio?  I don't see any such option from within android-studio.

Under dependencies I have:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

}

Comment: what is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: First try to upgrade your dependencies if possible, or even target higher SDKs. Also make sure that you have selected the support library Tools >> SDK Manager >> SDK Tools >> Support Repository. If things start to get desperate File >> Invalidate cache/Restart (do both). Lastly keep a backup of the code files and reinstall Android Studio. Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure there's no other errors in your project? This error can happen only because the project won't compile otherwise

Comment: If I comment out the line "import android.support.v7.app.ActivityCompat;" (having already commented out the method that uses this) the project compiles and runs just fine.  If I uncomment out the line (which causes ActivityCompat to appear in red, showing that it is not recognized) the project will not compile.  I ask again if those related directories (mentioned in my original post) are supposed to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the ActivityCompat class is no longer in the android.support.v7.app class.  I had to change my import to android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.  However for AppCompatActivity and AlertDialog I can use v7.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to delete build.griddle file in android package folder
2. And restart android studio. 
Some cases its work for me, chek this.

Comment: Not sure where to do that.  Any clarification appreciated.

Comment: On the project tab that is sideways, on the left of Android Studio. The program will generate these files again.

Comment: Well, I deleted it and now I get the message: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

There is still one build.gradle there that shows in parent "Module: app" but the project one is gone and was not regenerated.

I should have made a copy of it before I deleted it.  Now I can't compile at all.  Any idea how I can get it back?

Comment: Ok, I copied the build.gradle from a backup of the project, so am now back where I started with the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

> **Edited**

I suggest you that delete **android/m2repository** folder *(I suggest creating a backup first)* and install it offline like this:

1. Download the latest support repository from this [link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/).
2. Extract the downloaded zip file.
3. Copy the folder named m2repository from the extracted folder.
4. Navigate to extras/android directory in your SDK installation directory.

   For me it's:
   C:\Users\$usrname$\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\
5. Replace the existing m2repository folder with the one from the ZIP.
6. Restart Android studio.

Then Go

> File > Project Structure > app > Dependencies

Then click on **+** button and select **Library dependency**

In **"Choose Library Dependency"** dialogbox, search **com.android.support:appcompat**
then select **OK**.

[image: appcompat]

Comment: There already was a "com.android.support.appcompat-V7.25.3.1" line there and under the Scope column is says "Compile"

I did as you suggested and got another entry which was identical except that under the Scope column is said "Implementation"

I deleted the original line, exited android-studio attempted to recompile etc, and it still doesn't recogize the android.support.v7.app.ActivityCompat item.  As I asked in my original post, should all those directories under /Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7 be empty?

Comment: This directory contains all versions of This directory contains all versions of appcompat-v7 and should not be empty.

Comment: Thanks for your continuing help.  I now have entries in all of the directories and followed the rest of the steps.  However on the project structure screen it no longer will say Compile in the Scope column, but rather Implementation.  ActivityCompat still appears in red on import statement.